# My keras model gives me random predictions when I give it images

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm making a model to classify images and when I give it images using model.predict it gives me random outputs. model.evaluate_generator gives me an accuracy of 0.9530581049962875 and loss of 0.2506975952616229. The images are 64x64 with three channels

I've tried using other datasets and I get the same results.

I was wondering if there are any problems with my model architecture.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(.50))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.50))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.50))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Edit: My training code and code used for prediction

```py
batch_size = 60
pic_size = 64

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/DATASET/Training_Samples',
       target_size=(64, 64),
        color_mode='rgb',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="categorical",
        shuffle=True)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/DATASET/Test_Samples',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        color_mode='rgb',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="categorical",
        shuffle=False)



history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                            steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size,
                            epochs=150,
                            validation_data=validation_generator,
                            validation_steps = validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size)

from skimage.transform import resize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

my_image = plt.imread('image.jpg')
my_image_resized = resize(my_image, (64,64,3))

import numpy as np
probabilities = model.predict(np.array( [my_image_resized,] ))

print(probabilities)
```

Comment: No, this is generally a problem with the training or prediction loop, not with the model architecture. Include that information in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I've added the training and prediction code.

Comment: Please post your `model.compile` statement

Comment: Added the model.compile statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions that come up to my mind are:

- Try to reduce the number of `MaxPooling` layers as much as possible. Event the mildest max pool, `(2, 2)` as in your case, gets rid of 75% of data!
- Reduce dropout probability. If half of your nodes are shut down at each training iteration, it's somewhat hard to make them learn things (I know someone will disagree, that's my personal opinion based on my ML experience). I usually set it in the 0.1-0.25 range.
- Normally, you don't need all those filters. CNNs commonly start with a lower number of filters at the initial layers, that increases with the number of layers. In this way you'd only extract relevant informations from noisy pixel data, and make the Network elaborate more complex representations later on. I usually start with 32, and then go up to 64, 128 later. Please consider this is my personal rule of thumb (it always returned good results, but other architectures might also be great).

A part from that, you can try classical regularization techniques, such as: L1-L2 regularization or different weights initializations.

Also, please share the training code. The problem might be there, instead of in the model's architecture.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I will try out your suggestions!

Comment: This is a bit late, but, i have posted the training and prediction code